# swing question on resize controls on maximize

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I have  a `JFrame` with the following layout and components:

```
 _________________________________________ 
 |  __________________________________    | 
 |  |JTree   |   Panel2              | *  |
 |  |(Panel1)| (other controls)      |<-> |
 |  |________|_______________________|    |
 |__________*_____________________________|
```

These are in the contentpane of the main `JFrame`.
What I want is when I maximize the window, these components to resize accordingly.
What happens now is that they remain in their current size and there is a huge gap at the place I have the arrow and stars.(Side and bottom).
I would like to remain packed.
I have used null layout for content pane and dropped the components from a visual designer.
How can I make the controls always resize on mazimize?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the two panels to have equal size, each occupying half of the main window, use GridLayout:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
getContentPane().add(Panel1);
getContentPane().add(Panel2);
```

If you want one panel to have constant width, use BorderLayout:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
getContentPane().add(Panel1,BorderLayout.EAST);
getContentPane().add(Panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you want more complex behaviour, e.g. to maintain the 1:2 width ratio, you will have to use GridBagLayout which is the most powerful layout but also the most complicated:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
getContentPane().add(Panel1,new GridBagConstaints(0,0,1,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagLayout.BOTH,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
getContentPane().add(Panel2,new GridBagConstaints(1,0,1,1,2,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagLayout.BOTH,new Insets(0,0,0,0),0,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use null layout, don't use a form designer, but rather experiment with the various layout managers.  GridBagLayout may be one of the managers that could help you create a GUI as desired, but many try to avoid using this one unless necessary.  Many also nest JPanels each with its own layout manager so in effect nesting the layout managers.

Comment: You mean the problem is I am using a null layout in the contentpane?Also what is the problem with nesting JPanels?

Comment: To your first question: yes, you cannot use null layout if you expect your components to change size with change in top level window size. For this you **must** use layout managers.  For your second question: there is **no** problem using nested JPanels and in fact in must layout situations, it is preferred.

Comment: Then you've solved your original problem by using a visual designer?  If so congratulations and let's mark this thread "solved".

Comment: Do not take it personally.It is just that most answers just say do not use visual designers.But on the other hand there is an effort to build good visual designers e.g. netbeans, windows builder etc.The fact that I did not succeed my aim is due to my lack of knowledge on this.Not the visual editor problem

Comment: Visual designers can make nice layouts, but they can be somewhat inflexible.  You ask what is wrong with using them, and so I assumed that this means that they solved your original problem.  In my experience though, anything more than the most simple of layouts usually works out better by using the various layout managers, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I also see that you're getting many varied responses to your question, which is a very good thing.  Try them all out, and see which works best for you.

Comment: If I need to add only 1 control in a panel e.g. a jtable and I want it to have some distance from the edges what layout should I use?

Comment: Usually a JTable goes in a JScrollPane, and then the JScrollPane goes into the container (possibly a JPanel).  The layout will depend on whether you want the JScrollPane/Jtable to expand when the container expands (consider GridLayout or BorderLayout) or not (consider FlowLayout).  I'd then add an empty border to the container/JPanel with sides of whatever gap size you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you search SO you'll probably get many different opinions. There is one common truth though: you need to have at least a basic understanding of how a certain layout manager works before even thinking of using a visual designer.

Having said that, the best results I got, and what I currently use in production is a combination of the great [WindowBuilderPro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/) and MigLayout as a layout manager.

I actually use MigLayout as a table layout. I put my components in cells and I set each cell with attributes like "grow" - if I want to expand on resize, minimum/pref/max size, alignment, etc. I can set components to span across cells and I get exactly what I want.

The great thing about WindowBuilder is that you can change the generated code without messing the designer, and the generated code it's actually pretty :)